# Google OAuth2 for authentication redirect hangs

Tags: google-oauth

I've implemented a simple OAuth2 for Authentication login system that is working reliably on my dev server using a localhost redirect uri.

When testing from a production server, with updated redirect uri, the Google account permission interface opens up for the user logging in. After authorizing account access, the browser just hangs on "Waiting for accounts.google.com..." and doesn't go anywhere. At this point, I can see that the application has been granted access to my profile by viewing account permissions on my Google account dashboard.

If I change the redirect uri to an invalid one, I do get the invalid redirect uri Google error message back, so it looks like the redirection cannot reach my redirect uri. I can reach the reditect uri directly through a browser though. Any pointers?

Comment: Sorted. Turned out to be a coding issue with redirection attempted from within an async method.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem trying to create a "Login with Google" App. Since this was my first Google App, and I was also just first using the social networking setups in the software package which I bought BEFORE the Google API had changed, I was at a complete loss as where to start.

It finally dawned on me to redirect Google (via the App settings in the developer console) to a test web page on my site (instead of the page defined by the software package,) and all worked as expected, meaning Google redirected properly to the test page (which was actually just my root index.php).  This told me that because the Google API had changed, my software package functionality was obsolete, and I needed to explore the code there.